# timer trigger azure function cosmos db input binding with dynamic SQL Query

Tags: azure-functions

How to create **timer trigger based azure function** with cosmos db input binding with dynamic SQL Query? where "id" field is dynamic

```
[FunctionName("GetDocByID")]
public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer,
    TraceWriter log,
    [CosmosDB(
        databaseName: "Database",
        collectionName: "Collection",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "MyConnectionString",
        SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM c  where c.id = {id}")] IEnumerable<Entity> documents)
{
 //function body -- process retrieved document
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, I think it can't be implemented in azure function timer trigger. We can find an example with HttpTrigger in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#http-trigger-look-up-id-from-route-data-using-sqlquery-c) of Azure function binding cosmos db.
[image]

But in the example above, it needs to get the {id} from the "Route" property in HttpTrigger, unfortunately we can't use "Route" property in TimerTrigger. So I think TimerTrigger doesn't support this requirement.